# Android textField fill remaining height of parent

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I'm really new to android and I'm trying to do very basic stuff ..
I would like to have a layout which contains 2 textFields

- The first one should be 100 dp height
- The second one should fill the remaining height of the layout

This is what I have done for now :

```
// LinearLayout
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

// TextView1
final TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
textView1.setText(R.string.app_name);
textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textView1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lyp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
linearLayout.addView(textView1, lyp1);

// TextView2
final TextView textView2 = new TextView (this);
textView2.setText(R.string.app_name);
textView2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lyp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
linearLayout.addView(textView2, lyp2);
```

But I don't how to say that the second one should be juste after the first one and until the the bottom of the layout.

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: You can just set the size on pixels..., or use the relativeLayout rules, use below instead of end_of and AlignParentBottom for the textview2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative layout for such task. It's slower than LinearLayout and can be easily done with LinearLayout. Use layoutWeight, like in the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <TextView 
 android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 />
 <TextView 
 android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In order to set layout_weight from code, do the following:

```
    public static int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // LinearLayout
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    // TextView1
    final TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setText(R.string.app_name);

    textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lyp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPx(100));
    linearLayout.addView(textView1, lyp1);

    // TextView2
    final TextView textView2 = new TextView (this);
    textView2.setText(R.string.app_name);
    textView2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lyp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
    linearLayout.addView(textView2, lyp2);

    setContentView(linearLayout);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question with linearlayout but it's not doing what I want. I can't see the second textfield (the blue one) below the first textfield

Comment: I've fixed your sample. You forgot to set vertical orientation and gravity is not needed.

Comment: OK, gravity is needed, I added it back.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all you should use linear layout for this task.But if you want to put it in RelativeLayout then the solution is below*

1-You should set you second textView's height to match_parent

2-RelativeLayout.END_OF will align you layout to right side of textview1.So use RelativeLayout.BOTTOM

3-RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100); will set your textview's heght to 100 pixels (Pixel size varies with devices).So set height in dp like this

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float dp = displayMetrics.density; 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(100*dp));
```

**TRY this-**

```
//density of device
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dp = displayMetrics.density; 

// RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

// TextView1
final TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
textView1.setText(R.string.app_name);
textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textView1.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lyp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(100*dp));
lyp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
relativeLayout.addView(textView1, lyp1);

// TextView2
final TextView textView2 = new TextView (this);
textView2.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lyp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lyp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BOTTOM, textView1.getId());
relativeLayout.addView(imageView1, lyp2);

mainLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);
```